# ASP.NET MVC5 - DBContext Migration error in Package Console Manager of Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

Currently I am learning ASP.NET MVC5. So I am doing DBConext migration from package manager console of VS 2022 using command `add-migration "initial-mcmd-migration" -context MyContactManagerDBContext`.
I am facing below issue while doing the same. I am using EntityFrameworkCore v6.0.22 & .Net Framework v6.0

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at MyContactManagerData.MyContactManagerDBContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\Rahul Data\Training\Projects\Course\ContactWebEFCore6\MyContactManagerData\MyContactManagerDBContext.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

**Note:** Before that I executed console command - `add-migration "initial-cmd-migration"` & receive below output.

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.
```

Comment: Could you share your asppsetings and the code about the DBContext in the   Pogram.cs ?